# Is it secure to load balance 2 servers using proxy balancer using the public ip addresses of the 2 servers?

Tags: proxy, apache2, load-balancing

Is it a secure practice to loadbalance using public ips of servers as in the example below?

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>    
    # WebHead1
    BalancerMember http://198.x.x.x:80

    # WebHead2
    BalancerMember http://198.x.x.x:80

    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests

</Proxy>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for it to be particularly insecure; the only thing to keep in mind is that both of the balanced servers (or all of them) will probably reply to queries over the net - And a DoS directed to one of them will lead you to 50% (or 1/n) downtime, as the balancer will round-robin between them.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache **proxies** the client requests to your load balanced servers. Thus, the clients connect to the proxy, which in turn establishes a connection with one of the servers in backend pool.

The **client never comes to know of the IP address of the backend server pool**. Having said that, there is no reason that you should require a public IP for the backend servers. Public IPv4 addresses are scarce, and cost money. So relinquish, unless there is a specific use for them.